# Applying migrations in production CMS approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have read several articles on applying migration in production. I Understand it quite well but i think i want to know detailed about it. I have also read microsoft's documentations but it does not give me what i am looking for.
The `Database.Migrate()` method is being used in almost everything I read online about it. How does it work? no one explains it.
Assuming in a CMS platform, i want to apply new migrations, a new module is added on runtime and I have to run the migrations automatically because you won't want your users to be involved in the complexity of database operations just as wordpress does.
New modules may contain migration scripts if needed, they will contain a class which inherits from my base `DbContext` which they can add their module models and everything related to database.
I will then have to merge or load that class or assembly with the core.

1. How does `Database.Migrate` work?
2. Does it produce a migration script?
3. Does it add a migrations to the migration table as when performed online?
4. Do I need to pass a migration script to it or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Database.Migrate only applies migrations that have been generated. This is the same as command `dotnet ef database update` from CLI.
2. No, it does not. This is the thing that you need to do on your own or automate it with tool / script - [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#generate-sql-scripts)
3. As mentioned before it does not add any NEW migrations, only applies them.
4. I don' think you can do it. An easier way would be to create some script on deploy that will do the thing you want and revert the database in case of failure. I also advise you to think about migration that will affect data. What if someone will generate migration that will cause the lost of data?

Comment: so in your opinion this means the migration scripts have to be in the migrations folder then I can call the `Database.Migrate()` then it will take the migration and apply it? because this happens in production?

Comment: Yes, it will apply migrations that have not been applied before to the database. The one that you are creating with  - dotnet ef migrations add - command.